# What is the default format of the raw data in the external uvc -usb Camera - yuv420 or yuv422?

Tags: c, image-processing, camera, yuv

What is the default format of the data captured from the external uvc-usb compliant camera.is it **yuv420** or **yuv422** or it depends on the camera sensor.Can any one point to the docs related to conversion algorithm of one format to another. 
Rgds,
Softy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USB Video Class supports one packed 4:2:2 YUV format (YUY2) and one planar 4:2:0 
YUV format (NV12). ( http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/USB_Video_Class_1_1_090711.zip ). The default values depends on implementation ( it can also give you a MPEG2 or h264 stream).

I'll explain the idea behind the conversions, it can be optimized afterwards:

YUV422 picture has every 2 luma points (Y), stored together with their chromas ( U and V) like this: YUYV YUYV YUYV YUYV YUYV YUYV

YUV420 is planar so you first have all the Y, then all the U and then all the V. Also the U and V planes are halved ( every second line ignored), and only is a particular U (and V) value shared by 2 points in the same line, it is also shared with the 2 points beneath them on the next line.

Comment: why you wrote YUYV 6 times any specific reason?your doc looks good , I will go through it?

Comment: just wanted to show that 2 luma pixels and chroma + chroma are grouped together. No other reason.